# prevent loading shadobox selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

Is there a way to prevent load shadobox when use selenium?

I want to prevent loading the shadobox for this website when use selenium

busesromani.cl/site/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could execute arbitrary javascript to force it closed (or at least hide it)

Here is some pseudo-code to give you an idea:

Shadobox:

```
<div id="shadobox">some modal</div>
```

Use JavaScriptExecutor:

```
"document.findElementById('shadobox').style.display = 'none';"
```

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to invoke the actual JavaScript function to close it, and then execute that. for example:

```
<div id="shadobox"><span class="right" onclick="closeShadobox()">X</span>some modal</div>
```

Use JavaScriptExecutor:

```
"closeShadobox();"
```